# cell border 0px set for few cells but still showing in Opera

Tags: border, opera

This happens only in Opera Browser.
I created a table w simple border for every cell except few which should be borderless, everything looks fine in every major browser except in Opera. I've created jsFiddle that shows the problem.

I don't know if this is me doing something wrong or bug?

Html Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Lp.</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Number</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="clean" colspan=2></td>
    <td class="clean">Total:</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=5 class="total-clean"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=3 class="total-clean"></td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
    <td>1234.56</td>
</tr>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 11pt;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}
table tr td {
 border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 
}
table tr th {
 border: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
table tr .clean {
 border-left: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
 border-right: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;        
}
table tr .total-clean {
 border: 0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4krAQ/

Comment: You simply need `border: 0;`, why you need colors and solids for 0px?

Comment: I added this as test because simple border: 0; didnt work as well

Comment: When i chance table style to `border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px;` line dissapears but it doesnt look quite as i would like